# My Ubuntu touch Aquarius do not install any apps

Tags: ubuntu-touch, webapps

Since today 28/05/15 my Ubuntu touch aquarius do not install any apps  When I try to install an app I have the following message: install failed try later! what the heck is going on? Anyone!

Answer (score 0):

There was a data center outage yesterday that affected the app store (installing and updates), but it seems to be working now.